# How to sort PageRequest on String as numeric value

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I currently have a system in place which can filter and sort records in the database and return them as a Paged object. One of the lines is like this:

```
final PageRequest request = new PageRequest(this.pagingSettings.getPageNumber(),
            this.pagingSettings.getPageSize(), sortDirection, sortedBy);
```

This works correctly, but now I'm having the following situation. I'm trying to sort on a house number, which is a varchar in my Postgres database. For example, we have 1, 12, 111, 1004 but also 1A or 36-BASEMENT. When sorting on these (character) values, these would sort on: 1, 1004, 111, 12, 1A, ...

So, `sortedBy` is now a String, which in this case is `houseNumber`. I found out that using the `ORDER BY` argument `... ORDER BY NULLIF(regexp_replace(container_number, E'\\D', '', 'g'), '')::int";` in Postgres, the sorting would be exactly like I wanted: 1, 1A, 12, 111, ...

However, just changing the `sortedBy` String to `sortedBy = "NULLIF(regexp_replace(container_number, E'\\D', '', 'g'), '')::int";` does not seem to work.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to sort the character values in a PageRequest numerical, without changing the database?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

So basically you need to do two things:

1. Implement custom comparator,
2. Annotate the entity class.

#### Ad.1.

```
public class HouseComparator implements Comparator<House> {
    @Override
    public int compare(House h1, House h2) {

        String s1 = h1.getHouseNumber().split("[^0-9]")[0];
        String s2 = h2.getHouseNumber().split("[^0-9]")[0];

        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

You need to add some better handling of your cases. The above comparator says, that `h1` is less than `h2` when it begins with a smaller number and vise versa. For this comparator `12A` is equal `12B` but it's up to you.

#### Ad.2.

```
@SortComparator(HouseComparator.class)
List<House> findByHouseNumber(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I seek. The PageRequest makes it possible to have a paged response of the total list of objects. This could mean I have only 10 of the 200 objects available. I'm not sure on how to fit your solution in here. To me, it seems like post-sorting here. 
I'm going to see how to fit iin this solution and report back what it does.

Comment: I'm using `Page<House> houses = this.houseRepository.findAll(request);` Where should I use this Comparator then?

Comment: What db do you use?

Comment: I use a Postgres database.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that you have entity with a `String` filed and you want to sort it like `Long` with jpa Pageable.

**So you need to do following things:(Remember this only works with Oracle Database)**

1. Add a new filed in your entity with `Long` type
2. for the new filed use  `@Formula` in getter method and evoke `to_number()`

> ```
> @Entity
> public class testEntity{
>          private String oldField;  //Getter and Setter
>
>          private Long newField; //Setter
>
>          @Formula(value = "to_number(oldField)")
>          public Long getNewField() {
>                 return newField;
>          } 
>  }
> ```

3. in your service find sorted filed and change it to the `newfiled`

> ```
>  if (Objects.nonNull(pagingRequest.getSort()) && pagingRequest.getSort().getFieldName().equals("oldField")) {
>             pagingRequest.getSort().setFieldName("newField");
>  }
> ```

Comment: This solution is the best in my opinion, but one small update from my side: 
a) It will look better, when you will put `@Formula` around field declaration (it is not needed to put it on getter
b) when you will get error like 'Formula mappings are currently not supported', you may need to add `@NotAudited` annotation (more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327871/formula-mappings-are-currently-not-supported-hibernate-orm-envers
c) my case:
`
@Column(name="idx")
String idx;
@Formula("COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(idx, '^\\d+')), 0)")
@NotAudited
Long idxNumber;
`

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try the Spring Data `JpaSort` class which allows function calls.

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting) you will have something like :

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.lastname like ?1%")
  List<User> findByAndSort(String lastname, Sort sort);

repo.findByAndSort("targaryen", JpaSort.unsafe("LENGTH(firstname)"));
```

You could also use it with a Pageable object.