# Formula mappings are currently not supported - Hibernate ORM Envers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I use Hibernate Envers:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "user")
@Audited
class User()
{
    private String id;
    @Formula("(SELECT name FROM other c where c.id = id)")
    private Integer name;
}
```

it throws:

> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.FormulaNotSupportedException:
>   Formula mappings (aside from @DiscriminatorValue) are currently not
>   supported

How to calculate entity attributes with @Formula and Hibernate Envers?

FYI When I remove Hibernate Envers it works properly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that you're asking Envers to audit a `@Formula` annotated column, which presently isn't supported.  I have opened JIRA [HHH-11785](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11785) for the sole purpose of looking into this farther.

However, you should be able to annotate the formula field with `@NotAudited` and Envers should integrate just fine with that configuration.  The real issue is that it fails when it finds the formula-based field's history is to be tracked.

As an example:

```
@Entity
@Audited
class User {
  @Formula("SELECT name FROM Other ...")
  @NotAudited
  private String name;
  // other attributes
}
```

Comment: your code give me: h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'user0_.name' in 'field list' nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]

Comment: Did you verify your formula is valid?  The only code I suggested to you was to mark the field as not being audited so that Envers proceeded past your failure point.  I'd need more details to help further but it likely sounds like some invalid query being executed.

Comment: your example does not work, I added bracket like this:@Formula("(SELECT name FROM Other ...)")  and now it works

Comment: If you have to wrap the statement in `(` and `)` then that is a bug.  You shouldn't have to wrap the `@Formula` annotations.  I'll add a note in the JIRA regarding looking into this too.

Comment: If you could add the stacktrace of the error without the parenthesis to a comment in the JIRA mentioned, that would be quite helpful.

Comment: I got jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT r.id FROM user r WHERE r.id=user0_.id as ' at line 1

Comment: My hope was you'd add the full stack trace to the JIRA issue, not this post.

Comment: it does not depend on parenthesis in the oracle database, and it fails on application startup.