# JPA Hibernate Order by alphanumeric field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, alphanumeric

I am using **Jpa/Hibernate** to access **MariaDB** in a **Spring Boot** application

I am strugling to sort data by an alphanumeric field containng numbers that might end with one letter (pattern `\d+[a-z]?`)

e.g.

- 10
- 104
- 20a
- 100b

and I need them ordered like this

- 10
- 20a
- 100b
- 104

I a bulding my own query with the **Criteria Api** because I also have to do some complex filtering.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class EntryRepositoryImpl implements EntryRepositoryCustom {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public Page<Entry> get(MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters, Pageable pageable) {

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    //  count total number of filterd entries
    Long totalResultCount = getResultCount(parameters, criteriaBuilder);

    // build query to get filterd entries
    CriteriaQuery<Entry> selectQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Entry.class);
    Root<Entry> getRoot = selectQuery.from(Entry.class);
    CriteriaQuery<Entry> select = selectQuery.select(getRoot);

    addFilters(parameters, criteriaBuilder, getRoot, select);

    // add sorting
    List<javax.persistence.criteria.Order> sortOrders = JpaUtils.translateSorting(pageable,
        getRoot);
    select.orderBy(sortOrders);

    //  get one page of filterd entries
    List<Entry> results = getPageResults(pageable, select);
    return new PageImpl<>(results, pageable, totalResultCount);
  }

  /**
   * Translate spring to jpa sorting.
   */
  public static List<javax.persistence.criteria.Order> translateSorting(Pageable pageable,
      Root<Entry> root) {
    List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    if (pageable.getSort() != null) {
      pageable.getSort().iterator().forEachRemaining(orders::add);
    }

    return orders.stream().
        map(order -> {
          String[] parts = order.getProperty().split("\\.");
          String field = parts[0];
          Path path = parts.length == 2 ? root.join(field).get(parts[1]) : root.get(field);
          return new OrderImpl(path, order.isAscending());
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

I already have a custom comparator but it seems, there is no way to translate it so the DB could use it.

### So far I found the following solutions/ideas

- using [@SortComparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508209/how-to-sort-pagerequest-on-string-as-numeric-value), but it is not feasible for my use case because the ordering has to happen in the database, because there are over 500k complex rows.
- this [sql base solution](https://www.mpopp.net/2006/06/sorting-of-numeric-values-mixed-with-alphanumeric-values/) but don't know how to translate it into the Criteria Api.
- after looking at the function of `CriteriaBuilder` ([javadoc](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html)) I got the idea to split the value into the numeric and string parts and apply to orders but there is not function to split with a regular expression.

**Edit:**

For now I did split the field into 2 and use two sort expression.

Comment: `ordering has to happen in the database` why that?

Comment: Because of performance there are over 500k complex rows.

Comment: 1. You only sort by 1 field -> not complex. 2. You should probably never retrieve 500k rows from database in 1 go. You risk `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: why not firing native sql using hibernate?

Comment: @NarenderSingh I already build the translation of filter query I get from a rest api to criteria api queries. I only need to add this custom sorting, other wise I have to redo everything.

Comment: Will be much easier to sort local and not in database

Comment: @XtremeBaumer As you mentioned due to the number of entries I can not load all possible results an than sort local, that's why I need to sort in the DB.

Comment: I doubt that is possible to do what you need with `criteria`. What you can do is to split your column in database into 2 and sort by 2 columns

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thanks, I did split the field.